# Command line utilities for djvu?

Tags: software-recommendation, djvu

There is a nice utility called `pdftk` for combining pdf files, extracting portions of pdf files, and other routine conversions. Is there something similar that works on `djvu` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how well it compares to `pdftk`, but there is [Djvulibre](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/features.html). A quick overview of the tools it comes with:

> - **c44**: a wavelet-based continuous-tone image encoder (à la JPEG-2000).
> - **cjb2**: single page encoder for bitonal images (black and white scans).
> - **cpaldjvu**: encoder for palettized images (a la GIF, but better).
> - **bzz**: a general-purpose data compressor (a la bzip2).
> - **djvused**: a powerful command interpreter for manipulating DjVu documents.
> - **ddjvu**: converts DjVu documents to PBM/PGM/PPM images.
> - **djvudump**: displays the structure of a DjVu file.
> - **djvuextract**: extracts chunks from a DjVu file.
> - **djvumake**: assemble chunks into a DjVu file
> - **djvutxt**: extract the "hidden text" from a previously OCRed DjVu document.

You can install the djvulibre tool-suite on Ubuntu with:

```
sudo apt-get install djvulibre-bin
```